# More efficient way of setting fillStyle color for canvas (via a string)?

Tags: html, canvas

I need to change my fill color dynamically while animating some elements. I'm wondering if there's any more efficient way of setting the current fillStyle than building a string, then having the browser parse it again?:

```
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + "," + a + ")";
```

I already have the r,g,b,a components as integers, any way to just give them directly to the system instead of jumping through this hoop?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the only way to assign a `fillStyle` is via a string that contains a valid color value.

From [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-2dcontext-20110525/#dom-context-2d-fillstyle)

> context . fillStyle [ = value ]
> Returns the current style used for filling shapes.
>
> Can be set, to change the fill style.
>
> The style can be either a string containing a CSS color,
> or a CanvasGradient or CanvasPattern object. Invalid values are ignored.